# I was fired from Admin. Asst. position, after 2 months from cut-throat company, for making a typo in an email to clients

Tags: interviewing, resume, employer

1. Should I include this job in my resume.
2. If future employers ask if I've been fired, what is the best thing to say?

I was an administrative assistant I really didn't like working in an environment of fear and manipulation, but I thought I'd try to stick it out. I ended up getting fired for an email mistake.

Comment: Related: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/6024/325, http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/31150/325, http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/17906/325, http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/32369/325.  I'm putting this question on hold because we can't tell you what to do in this specific question (see links in close notice above), but maybe these other questions will help you.  Thanks and good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You can go either way:

1. If you choose to include the position in your resume, you can state why you left as "they provided an extremely stressful professional environment". If you can find favorable references from senior co-workers or other managers, that might be an extra reason for you to include the position in your resume. If you can't get positive references from anyone, then it would be a justification for not including the position in your resume.
2. You can choose not to include the position in your resume, as you have only been in it for two months.

Answer (score 2):

If it was only two months, I'd suggest simply leaving this out of your resume. It isn't worth getting into a debate about whether the termination was justified or not, especially since you presumably aren't going to use anyone from that company as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if an interviewer will ask you about it, it's best to admit that you got fired and also provide some details if they ask for them.

However, I would like to point out that most interviewers will probably not believe that the tiny typo got you fired, simply because it's a little ridiculous. I know I wouldn't believe it.

They will most likely imagine that you were a poor performer and the email typo was the excuse the company needed to let you go. Now, I doubt the interviewers will explicitly say this to you but, in order to crush those suspicions as best as possible, be extra prepared to prove that you will be a valueable employee. References from people currently working at your last company have the highest chance of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I include this job in my resume.

Unless this was your first every job, it would make sense to include the job in your resume.

That way, there is no gap to be addressed.

> If future employers ask if I've been fired, what is the best thing to
>   say?

The best thing to say is always the truth.

In this case you say "Yes" if asked if you were fired.
And if the interviewer wants more details, you provide them.

You should also be prepared to discuss how this new job will be different.